# CS0120, trying to send data through RadioButton to ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been having some trouble trying to do this code of mine, I am trying to set up a program for a Visitor Registration with a Custom Dialog I made, it has 4 radiobuttons and I cant do anything to fix it right now. 
And heres some screenshots for the references of the forms. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHLcC.jpg

My Form1 code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _2021415_20T1_L5IS_PP1_Assessment_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your name");
            }
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your surname");

            }
            if (textBox3.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your mobile number");

            }
            if (textBox4.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your email");

            }
            if (numericUpDown1.Text == "0")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the time");

            }
            if (numericUpDown2.Text == "0")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the time");

            }




            else
                listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem + " - John Doe" + " at " + numericUpDown1.Text + ":" + numericUpDown2.Text);

        }
```

Then my Form2 code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _2021415_20T1_L5IS_PP1_Assessment_2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                Form1.listBox1.Items.Add("");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what problem you're facing...

Comment: Oh sorry, the problem I am facing is that I cant communicate between the forms, I am trying to use a Radiobutton from form2 to add to my Listbox for the beginning of a meeting

Comment: Forms are just classes like any other, so you can add whatever methods you need in order to pass data around.  Let the forms fiddle with their own controls though and just pass the data. You can obviate the whole issue though by using Tab Controls

Answer (score 0):

Forms are classes and they need to call methods on each other or access properties of each other to pass data between them. They also need to have access to the objects of each other.

In your code, Form1 creates an object of Form2 and opens it as dialog but Form2 does not know current instance of Form1 which opened the dialog. So you need to fix that first.

You can do that by having a constructor in Form2 which takes an object of Form1 as argument.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
    }
    //
    // Rest of the code of Form2...
    //
}
```

Here Form2 knows about the instance of Form1 which opened the Form2 as dialog. Now on click of OK button Form2 should be able to pass the data of radio button to the Form2.

For this, Form1 can have a method which will accept the data as a string and add it to its listbox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
    //
    // Rest of the code of Form1...
    //
}
```

Now Form2 can call this method on click of OK button.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
    }
    //
    // Rest of the code of Form2...
    //
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            this.form1.AddItem("");
        }
    }
}
```